# SwiftUI how to delete from ForEach by ID, not index

Tags: swiftui

The following code makes me uncomfortable.

```
struct HistoryView: View {

    @ObservedObject var history: History

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(history.getSessions()) { sess in
                Text("Duration: \(sess.duration)")
            }.onDelete(perform: self.onDelete)
        }
    }

    private func onDelete(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that `History` is a very asynchronous thing. It's a model connected to CloudKit. It could be getting updates in the background. Ideally, if it updates, this `View` would update immediately and the indexes would still be accurate, but I much prefer to get a set of the *identifiers* to delete, not set of indexes. Is there a way to do this? Note: those "history sessions" conform to `Identifiable` as required by `ForEach`, so they all have IDs. In my case they are `UUIDs`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help lock history sessions while you delete the index you selected:

```
struct HistoryView: View {

@ObservedObject var history: History
private let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.xxx.yyy.zzz")

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(history.getSessions()) { sess in
            Text("Duration: \(sess.duration)")
        }.onDelete(perform: self.onDelete)
    }
}

private func onDelete(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
    syncQueue.sync {
        // do the delete
     }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to help, because to use a lock effectively here, you'd need the scope of the lock to include the call to history.getSessions().